# Is there some way I could get VSCode's JavaScript syntax color to IntelliJ/WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, color-scheme

I really like the way Visual Studio Code syntax color looks in the editor when I'm writing JavaScript or React. I would like to use WebStorm for JavaScript but their JavaScript syntax color is not so nice. This might seem like a small thing but to me VSCode is much more readable than WebStorm.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Better VS Code from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes or https://github.com/lenny1882/vscode-dark-plus-webstorm;
I'd also suggest looking at  [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) plugin - it's a UI theme + a set of editor color schemes

Comment: I installed Material, but the javascript highlighting remains the same. Any idea?

Comment: The material colour scheme doesn't look like vs code but it adds nice icons and design to your IDE. As such you need to install a colour scheme that resembles VS code as mentioned above.

Comment: You can check https://github.com/mkubdev/material-vscode-jetbrains who get the colorScheme from @lena and the .xml for the Material UI plugin, to match the UI color from VSCode dark+ theme.